# What's the best balance price/quality audio recorder for meetup and small conf

Tags: audio, audio-recording

I am doing some **meetup recording** and I want to automate the thing.

Here are my current devices to record any meetup:
- OBS
- logitech c922 
- AverMedia LGP Lite

I need a better sound that the webcam sound. Ideally it will not be on the speaker but I know that a microphone tie would be the best choice. I have tried with a H2n ZOOM but I think we can do better.

#### What are you recommending?

*Ideally the price should be between 50-200$*.

Comment: Have you tried an H4 Zoom? It's in the price range.

Comment: well, I think as the H2N it's too far from the speaker but maybe it's enough? Did you already try to use the H4 standing on a desk 2 meters away from the speaker?

Comment: Don't underestimate the consequences of a crappy audio environment.  See https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/17318/microphone-for-indoor-interview/17320#17320 and in particular the video link it refers to: http://nofilmschool.com/2015/08/24-sound-basics-will-help-you-lay-sturdy-foundation

Comment: What is the reason the microphone needs to be that far? I feel that distance (2m) is going to be an issue with most equipment.

Comment: it's just more convenient to have one microphone. ut regarding comments I'll probably invest and either a micro tie, any advice for it?